# Iptables: some ports are closed despite being open by my iptables; can it be something else?

Tags: iptables, port

Beginner question. I set up the following iptables rules:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Réinitialise les règles
sudo iptables -t filter -F 
sudo iptables -t filter -X 

# Bloque tout le trafic
sudo iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP 
sudo iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP 
sudo iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP 

# Autorise les connexions déjà établies et localhost
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 

# ICMP (Ping)
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 

# SSH
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 

# DNS
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 

# HTTP
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 

# SSL
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 

# FTP 
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT 

# Mail SMTP 
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 

# Mail POP3
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 

# Mail IMAP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 

# NTP (horloge du serveur) 
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT


#Flood ou déni de service
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
```

Unfortunately ports 53, 143, 443 remained closed.
I tied to reboot my server and reload the rules; but still the same issue (I am using a OVH VPS). Can the ports be closed by something else?

Comment: Please show us your actual rules with the command `iptables-save`.

Comment: iptables-save does not return anuthing

Comment: Are you sure your rules are doing anything then? What happens when you flush them all and set the policy to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your policies are applied one after the other. Your default policy should then be applied at the end, not the begining. So you should remove this block:

```
# Bloque tout le trafic
sudo iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
```

and add this one at the end of your script:

```
# Bloque tout le trafic
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: Policies are not rules, it doesn't matter whether you set them at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: That and you should not apply the same rules on output (connections are not between ports 53-53 80-80 and so on)

Comment: oups, you're right, I replied too quickly. Updated the response to change rules to policy (which is probably what was intended first time)

Comment: Does not change anything to put policies at the end.

Comment: @BSONetworkSolutions Your post was right the first time, it's your understanding of netfilter/iptables that is incorrect. What you add one after the other in netfilter are rules, but what you set with the `-P` argument is that chain's `policy`. The policy doesn't have any ordering, it's a setting of the chain and thus it doesn't matter if it's at the beginning or end.